# R plot Odds Ratio for each value in logistic regression

Tags: r, data-visualization, logistic

I am trying to replicate the method in section 3a of [this paper](https://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-79pdf/doc-10027230) where, for a logistic regression model, they plot the functional relationship between a continuous variable and the odds for developing the outcome (using a smoothing spline).

[image]

I was wondering how do you replicate this from an R `glm` model, as example:

```
x <- c( 0,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,10 )
y <- c( 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1 )

m <- glm( y ~ x , family = "binomial" )
summary(m)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6671  -0.5085  -0.3056   0.7814   1.6066  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -3.7311     1.9556  -1.908   0.0564 .
x             0.6906     0.3611   1.912   0.0559 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 20.19  on 14  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 13.47  on 13  degrees of freedom
AIC: 17.47

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

how can I extract the OR for each single value in order to replicate the example? Is the `m$effect` or what other parameter? I know how to plot predicted values, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685921/plot-logistic-regression-curve-in-r), but this is a different question

Comment: From the paper you cite: "functional relationship between time between last ASI therapy and surgery versus the odds for developing hypotension *using a smoothing spline*" [my emphasis].  The model you fit is *linear* (on the log-odds scale).  The model you fit and the model used to produce the graph are fundamentally different beasts. So the short answer is "you can't".  Or rather, the graph you get from the `glm` is rather uninteresting: It's a horizontal straight line.

Comment: @Limey thank you for your reply. I'm fitting a logistic regression model as they are, otherwise we won't get ORs (that I know how to extract for the variable itself but not for each value as they show in the plot). If they use a linear model, how did they got to a linear model from a logistic one?

Comment: Your logistic model is *linear* in the predictors (albeit, as I previously said, on the log odds scale).  That's why your plot of OR against time post op is a straight line.  Their logistic model is a spline, which is why their graph is a curve.  If this is the main point you would like to discuss, I suggest migrating to StackExchange, as it is more of a stats question than a programming question.